# Dynamic width of collection view cell - Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I want to make Cell width dynamic with respect to its content. i've tried by calculating label width and then assigning it to cell frame but couldn't achieve this because label is not returning it actual width.

```
public void UpdateCell(string text)
{
    label.Text =  text;
    this.ContentView.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, label.Frame.Width, this.ContentView.Frame.Height);
}
```

Comment: I think you should resize the contentview  in the correct place ,refer to here : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/72296/collectionview-cell-width-is-not-changing-on-different-screen-sizes

Comment: I've checked this but my scenario is different I know cell size is reflecting a change if I put code in GetSize method of delegate class but I will only give static value to this method because I cannot access my views from here

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NSString's `GetSizeUsingAttributes` to calculate the `CGRect` of a string, you can then use that `CGRect` to retrieve the width:

```
using (var labelString = new NSString(label.Text))
{
    var size = labelString.GetSizeUsingAttributes(new UIStringAttributes() { Font = label.Font });
    ContentView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, size.Width, ContentView.Frame.Height);
}
```

Comment: I've updated the code and I also checked that this function is returning different values with respect to its content but my cell is still not reflecting the different width